Path-following methods being a 1-phase method
I read in Vanderbei's "Linear Programming" that "The path-following method is a one-phase method. This
means that the method can begin from a point that is neither primal nor dual feasible and it will proceed from there directly to the optimal solution."
However, it seems to me that what he describes is more about not having "primal/dual feasibility" rather than not having "an interior point." Calling it a one-phase method (bypassing the first phase to find an initial point that is inside the feasible region) is a stretch. Is it true that you can start anywhere, even not inside the feasible region?
If so, would it be weird to call it "interior-point method" as I believe the "central path" lies inside the feasible region. Does it move to inside the region?
Edit: I am confused because the common geometric intuition for IPM is to optimize on a convex feasible region determined by (Ax <= b, x >= 0) by starting from a point inside this region and following the central path to a "corner" of this region. Does this still hold? Is it okay to start outside of the feasible region?

Consider the standard primal dual pair:
$\min c^{T}x$
subject to
$Ax=b$, $x \geq 0$
and the dual
$\max b^{T}y$
subject to
$A^{T}y+z=c$,
$z\geq 0$.
In the "infeasible" version of the primal-dual interior point methods, we start with $x\geq 0$ and $z \geq 0$, but otherwise we don't require feasibility with respect to $Ax=b$.
Yes, the central path is in the feasible set- path following methods start off of the central path and converge toward the central path.

The common geometric intuition for IPM is to optimize on a convex feasible region determined by (Ax <= b, x >= 0) by starting from a point inside this region and following the central path to a "corner" of this region. Does this still hold? Is it okay to start outside of the feasible region?

@VũLêThếAnh that's simply incorrect.  As explained above, the "infeasible interior point method" starts with a solution that is feasible with respect to $x,z \geq 0$ but infeasible with respect to $Ax=b$ and $A^{T}y+z=c$.  Newton's method fixes the infeasibility with respect to the linear equations.

Thanks! I also realize it can start from outside of the polytope trying to go inside. So much for "interior" now.
